# How to add a "pre" middleware to mongoose model AFTER creating the model

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I need to add a `pre` mongoose middleware to a model (not schema) after the model was created from the schema.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const FooSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    foo: String
});
const FooModel = mongoose.model('Foo', FooSchema);
```

And then in the middle of the runtime

```
 FooModel.schema.pre('save', myMiddleware);
```

However, after some debugging, I found that all the middewares must be added *before* creating the model.

Is there a way to add my middleware **after** model creation?

Comment: @SyedAyeshaBebe thanks. But it does not answer my question at all.

Comment: Why are you trying to modify the schema ( and assigning method hooks is modifying ) to an existing model? If anything you likely want to register a new model instead. You should explain your intent rather than just the after effect.

Comment: You can use `FooModel.schema.post('save', middleware)` [schema.post](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-post)

Comment: @AlexandruOlaru tried that. Doesn't work for `pre`

Comment: Faced same issue. I want to add middleware after creating a model from the schema. Is there any workaround to register middleware after create the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not such possibility in Mongoose unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly what you wanted, but I found a workaround to this using statics.
You wrap your schema with a function that register and calls your middlewares if they were set. Like in this example where I add pre save hooks

```
function wrap(schema) {
  const middleware = {};
  schema.statics.setMiddleware = (name, func) => {
    middleware[name] = func;
  };
  schema.pre('save', async function () {
      if (middleware.save) await middleware.save.bind(this)();
  });
  return schema;
}
```

In your model registration you wrap the Schema

```
module.exports = model('foo', wrap(Schema));
```

To add a middleware after model creation you call `setMiddleware`

```
MyModel.setMiddleware('save', function () {
  console.log(this);
});
```

This is the basic idea, but could be extended so that all hooks are registered in the wrap function and allow multiple middlewares to be set, which in this way it doesn't